# Не запускается метод onClick() в android

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь написать форму логина/пароля, но метод `onClick()` не работает.

Задавал тремя разными способами, остановился на таком

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.myapplication.R;
import com.example.myapplication.data.model.MainMenuActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView coursesText, appText;
    EditText usernameForm, passwordForm;
    Button loginButton;
    ImageButton infoButton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);

        coursesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        appText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        usernameForm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordForm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        infoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (usernameForm.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
                        passwordForm.getText().toString().equals("12345")) {
                    Intent goToMainMenu = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(goToMainMenu);
                }else{
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Ваш логин и пароль неверны", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 1, -1);
                    LinearLayout toastContainer = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
                    ImageView pic = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                    pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture);
                    toastContainer.addView(pick, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**Мой xml-файл**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ui.login.LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="269dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="324dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/login_placeholder"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="269dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/password_placeholder"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="153dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#EDA4A4"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/log_in"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="62dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="@string/app"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="@string/courses"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        android:contentDescription="@string/info_button"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Как сделать, чтобы вызвать этот метод?

При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит

Comment: XML файл как называется? Не стоить одновременно задавать обработчик в XML и в коде. Выберите что-то одно.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, activity_login2

Comment: Удалите `onClick` из XML и все должно работать.